# Powershell command Get-Service and Get-WmiObject returning false in Jenkins file

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I have to run a powershell script in a Jenkins pipeline.  The version of Powershell we are using is 5.1.
I don't have a problem with most of the commands in the script.
I am trying to determine if a window service exists.  If it does, I don't need to copy the exe, if it doesn't I want to copy the exe to the window server.
This is the section of code that is the issue:

```
 Write-Host "Unzipped the folder"

 if(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='TMWTMSListener'")
 {
    Write-Host "TMWTMSListener Service exists"
    Stop-Service -Name "TMWTMSListener" -NoWait
    Write-Host "TMWTMSListener Service stopped"
                    
    Copy-Item -Path "$tempDeployExtractPath\*.jar" -Destination "$deployPath" -Force
    Copy-Item -Path "$tempDeployExtractPath\*.xml" -Destination "$deployPath" -Force 
 }
 else {
    Write-Host "TMWTMSListener Service does not exist"
    Copy-Item -Path "$tempDeployExtractPath\*.jar" -Destination "$deployPath" -Force
    Copy-Item -Path "$tempDeployExtractPath\*.exe" -Destination "$deployPath" -Force
    Copy-Item -Path "$tempDeployExtractPath\*.xml" -Destination "$deployPath" -Force
```

}

I have also tried this command in the if statement:

```
if(Get-Service -DisplayName "TMWTMSListener" -ErrorAction Ignore)
```

The if statement is always false even though when I test both of these commands on the server in Powershell the if statement is true.
Even if I stop the service the commands when run on the server in Powershell returns true.  It can find the service.

Is there any work around for this issue?
How can I store the results of the Get-Service or Get-WmiObject  command in Jenkins?

Comment: this `when I test both of these commands on the server in Powershell the if statement is true` indicates that you are running the code on two different systems. so ... are you running the code on a system where the target service is running?

Comment: yes.  I ran both commands on the target server that is running the service.  The if statement is true.  But running the commands in the Jenkins pipeline, returns false

Comment: ah! that makes more sense ... thank you. [*grin*] ///// i have been told that some orchestration apps have a nasty habit of running the 32bit version of PoSh instead of the 64bit version. have you checked that? you can use `[System.Environment]::Is64BitProcess` to check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the above problem.  I needed to set the ComputerName in the command. It was looking on the build box for the service.  It needed to look on the remote server.
this is the command I used to determine if the service existed

```
$ServiceResult = Get-Service -ComputerName "C0016581" -DisplayName "TMWTMSListener" -ErrorAction Ignore
```